# Wikidata - Is this query possible?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, wikidata, wikidata-api

**I want to do a query on [WikiData](https://www.wikidata.org/) where I get all items, that are somehow connect to another item.**

For example I have Item "[Vienna](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1741)" (Q1741). Now I want to get all Items, that have Item Vienna in *any* property.

The API I currently use is the one from [wmflabs](http://tools.wmflabs.org/autolist/index.php). Here I can do a query like

```
claim[189:1741]
```

This gives me every item with property "Place of discovery" (P189) = "Vienna" (Q1741).

But what I want is something like

```
claim[*:1741]
```

to get all items where *any property* fits "Vienna", for example "Birthplace" (P19), "Place of Death" (P20) or *anything* else. But wildcards are not working here.

**Is this possible? How?**

---

*PS:* I'm not bound to this API, I could use any API to wikidata accessible via JS. There are also some SparQL endpoints to Wikidata-Dumps available (like                       [wikidataldf](http://wikidataldf.com/)), but I don't know how stable they are. But if anyone could help with a solution using **SPARQL**, I would be glad, too.

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like this:

```
SELECT ?node WHERE {?node ?pred wd:Q1741}
```

see on [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fnode%20WHERE%20%7B%3Fnode%20%3Fpred%20wd%3AQ1741%7D%20%20%20%20%0A)

Answer (score 2):

you can use sparql query to Dbpedia to get result for you particular resource, which here is [Vienna](http://dbpedia.org/page/Vienna).
To get all property and their value of resource Vienna use can use

```
select ?property ?value where { 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Vienna> ?property ?value
 }
```

[Check here](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FVienna%3E%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%0D%0A%20filter%28langmatches%28lang%28%3Fvalue%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)
You can choose specific properties of resource using sparql query like this .

```
select ?country ?density ?timezone ?thumbnail where { 
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Vienna> dbpedia-owl:country ?country;
 dbpedia-owl:populationDensity ?density;
dbpedia-owl:timeZone ?timezone;
dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail.
}
```

[Check](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fcountry%20%3Fdensity%20%3Ftimezone%20%3Fthumbnail%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FVienna%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%3B%0D%0Adbpedia-owl%3ApopulationDensity%20%3Fdensity%3B%0D%0Adbpedia-owl%3AtimeZone%20%3Ftimezone%3B%0D%0Adbpedia-owl%3Athumbnail%20%3Fthumbnail.%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

> *But what I want is something … to get all items where any property fits "Vienna"[.]*

In SPARQL this is very easy.  E.g., on [DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/):

```
select ?resource where {
  ?resource ?property dbpedia:Vienna 
}
```

[SPARQL results (limited to 100)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fresource%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fresource%20%3Fproperty%20dbpedia%3AVienna%20%0D%0Afilter%28%20%3Fproperty%20!%3D%20owl%3AsameAs%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

There are already some SPARQL endpoints for Wikidata available. However, they are still beta and only reflect the data from the last dump.

Your query would be [this one](http://wikisparql.org/sparql?showquery=SELECT%20%3Fresource%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fresource%20%3Fproperty%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2FQ1741%3E%20.%0D%0A%3Fresource%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fontology%23Item%3E%0D%0A%7D)

See also [this help page on Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access)